# How to change the mapped TFS location from team foundation server ?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I mapped a project in TFS in wrong location, after that I did undo pending changes and try to remap the project to correct location.But when try to remap, it automatically mapped to previously mapped location which I gave mistakenly.
So how can I map it to correct location.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map a solution to team foundation server, It will automatically create a workspace in your pc, so afterwards that workspace used feature mapping, so you have to remove the that workspace in you workspaces.
Steps -

- Go to workspaces.

  File - > Source control - > Advanced - > workspaces..
- Double click on your current workspaces.
- Then find the workspace which you mistakenly added and remove it.
- Now you can map to your solution to correct location.